# Hide RecyclerView item when image path is empty?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` shows a list of logos, I want to hide an item if its path is empty.
I tried using `vh.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` not working ,I tried applying layoutparam if height is 0, also not working.

I cannot filter out the list to only contain non-empty paths because I will get item position issues later

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( StudioAdapter.StudioViewHolder vh, int position) {
        final String path = StudioLogoPaths.get(position);
        if (StudioLogoPaths.get(position).isEmpty()) {
            vh.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Glide.with(vh.itemView.getContext()).load(path).into(vh.logoImage);
        }       
    }
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/transparent_ripple">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/studio_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should filter out the items you don't want to show. I mean that you should pass to the Recycler view a list that does not contain the item you don't want to show

Comment: I already thought of that, but it gives me position issues in other parts of my code, so that is why I need a different approach

Comment: your if condition is working , mean is it going inside if ?

Comment: I just set break point to check , no it is working, so I guess the condition is not correct somehow

Comment: It is normally not a good idea to use the position to identify an item unless you have to optimise. When accessing an item try to look by a unique ID instead of the position

Comment: I don't have other options, so, I also tried `(StudioLogoPaths.get(position) == null)` it is the same

Comment: the condition was not correct, I had to change it to `file.exists()` problem solved , thank you all

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution that works for me

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( StudioAdapter.StudioViewHolder vh, int position) {
        final String path = StudioLogoPaths.get(position);
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()){
            Glide.with(vh.itemView.getContext()).load(path).into(vh.logoImage);
        } else {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vh.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
            params.width = 0;
            vh.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
            vh.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there something wrong with my  answer?

Comment: Although it is working in this case, this is not the approach you should take. Like @kingston said, the RecyclerView should receive a list without the items that should be hidden. If the last starts with 1.000 items that will be hidden and 2 items that are shown, 1.002 ViewHolders are created. If you filter the list beforehand, only 2 ViewHolders are created making you app a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks , you are totally right, and I did that before asking this question , but I have a class that deals with all item regardless of if they have file or not, so position of the file will be changed , and that is not what I want, I hope you get what I mean

Comment: If your class and the RecyclerView are so tightly coupled that something like `listAdapter.submitList(paths.filter { it.isEmpty() })` is not possible, that is already a red flag.

Comment: No that is not the case , what I'm trying to say is that, for example the original list of logos let's say is 20 items , now I pick item 15 as an example, after filtering it the list comes down to 10 , from this 10 the index of 15 becomes 6 , and this is problematic because even after filtering I have to compare it to the original list, I hope I'm clear this time